# Prevent application from being active while opening a utility window(spark) in Air application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, desktop-application, flex4.5

I am trying to open a utility a window that I have created in spark.

The scenario is: I have to open utility window when application get deactivated. and utility window should get closed when application get activated.

But on Deactivate when I open window `myUtilityWin.open(false)`, as window get open my application get activated and utility  window get closed.

MyUtilityWindow.mxml

```
<s:Window xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
 xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" backgroundAlpha="0" systemChrome="none" type="utility" showStatusBar="false" transparent="true" alwaysInFront="true">
```

// code

How I open MyUtilityWindow :

```
 myUtilityWin = new MyUtilityWindow();
 myUtilityWin.open(false);
 myUtilityWin.alwaysInFront = true;
 myUtilityWin.orderToFront();
```

How can i achieve the goal?

Comment: How are you detecting when your application is Deactived? The `Application.deactivate` event?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,Yes on Application.deactivate i show the utility window.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the use of the `deactivate`,`activate` events. `Event.DEACTIVATE` and `Event.ACTIVATE` are program wide events that are dispatched by all event dispatchers "when the Flash Player or AIR application operating loses or gains system focus" [deactivate reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#event%3adeactivate), [activate reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#event%3aactivate).

When you call `Window.open(); Window.orderToFront();` during the `deactivate` you are requesting system focus which triggers the `activate` broadcast on the next screen refresh. There is no way to avoid this, this is coded in the the base classes of Flash, you'd have to rewrite `EventDispatcher` in order to stop it.

My recommendation would be to build either a static class (or use the top level application to handle your `Window` objects.

Application Class Example:

```
public function openWindow(window:Window,openActiveWindow:Boolean,alwaysInFront:Boolean,orderToFront:Boolean):void{
    window.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE,windowClosed);
    window.open(openActiveWindow);
    window.alwaysInFront = alwaysInFront;
    if (orderToFront) window.orderToFront();
}
private function windowClosed(event:Event):void{
    if (event is myUtilityWindow){
        //utility window just closed act accordingly
    }
    else {
        //a window of another type closed open utility window
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks cyan , actually i am not closing the main window , m showing this utility window when Application get focus out or minimized.

i ll try what you have suggested , and let you know soon.

Comment: Same problem in principle, just a different `Event`, by attaching this to the `Application` object your triggering this loop back. When you open a `Window` you `maximise` the application as well. The `Application` object represents your whole program, you need to attach your event listeners to your `Window`s so you can react to those changes instead of trying to react to changes at the `Application` which is a wrapper arround all the `Window`s

Comment: Specifically, the event in this case is `NativeWindowDisplayStateEvent.DISPLAY_STATE_CHANGE` ([ref](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Window.html#event:displayStateChange))